# What is the correct relative pronoun in the blank?

Tags: grammar

These days, technical writing is a promising field (     ) you can find a good job.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I think it's 'in which". 
and you? (what do you think?)

Answer (score 1):

The most correct and most formal way would be

> These days, technical writing is a promising field in which you can find a good job.

In less formal contexts, this would also be acceptable

> These days, technical writing is a promising field which you can find a good job in.

Comment: Thank you! Jacob Lee-hart! :)

I agree with your answer.
but my english teacher said that this answer is "whose" (I don't know why?) .
I couldn't agree that. so, I decided post it.

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly a relative pronoun, yet a *relative word* that combines well enough with *field* in this context: **where**. Here's a similar example from the book *How to Get a Good Job After 50: A step-by-step guide to job search success* (by Rupert French):

> ... social media enables you to to more easily build a network of
>   contacts within the field **where** you are hoping to find employment.

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=0mUMBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA153&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U0TJvVGilClGXMPQ-OucJOTW03a6A&w=1280

Another one (from: *Layoff Survival Guide: Are You About to Be Laid Off or Fired?* - by Ade Asefeso):

> It doesn't really matter if the job you are going to take part-time
>   participation at is related to the field **where** you have previously
>   worked.

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=9cUYAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT86&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U13loi3yWZ6ikwBtVEbddWV9fGv8w&w=1280